# php variable is not array. Inserted data using mysql_query in the variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

It says that the `$c1` is not an array. If I remove the 7th line, then it gives this error message:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

I want to know how you can make `$c1` an array or what am I doing wrong?

```
$bag = $_POST['bag'];      //from a Form.

$query = "SELECT info FROM users";
$c1 = array();
$c1 = mysql_query($query);

if(is_array($c1))
{

    foreach ($c1 as $check)
    {
        $check_bag = $check['info'];
        if ($bag == $check_bag)
        {
            echo"Bla bla bla bla.";
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how you fetch data with the obsolete deprecated legacy mysql extension. I have the impression that you're trying to build an app from random bits of code gathered from Google. You should consider using books, tutorials or the official manual.

Comment: @Baldrs: They're different. See the documentation: [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query)

Comment: While this *might* work, it's completely the wrong way to go about doing this. You absolutely **must** learn to use the `WHERE` clause rather than fetching all results and filtering in the application.

Comment: I have read many books of php but I also have my university to attend, so I don't have that much time now. I also use $pdo->query() but please tell me regarding this example.

Answer (score 4):

First, and foremost, you should not use the mysql library any longer.  It is not secure, and is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.  Upgrade to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  For more information, refer to this article:[Choosing a DB API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Second, the reason it's not an array is because of this line:

`$c1 = mysql_query($query);`

At this point, $c1 is a mysql resource, not an array.

In order to access the data, you would remove your if statement `if(is_array($c1))`, and then you need to change your loop to look like so:

```
while($check = mysql_fetch_array($c1)) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

As a final comment, the code in your question is inefficient, and uses more resources than necessary.  A simplified version would utilize a WHERE clause in your query like so:

```
$query = 'SELECT info FROM users 
    WHERE info="' . mysql_real_escape_string($bag) . '"';
```

This would return only results that match, rather than all items from user.

Comment: Beaten to the punch. +1.

Comment: I did it like you said. But now it gives the following error:
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given..
I know that the only problem is that $c1 is not an array. I need to know how to fix this. And now I used the query:
$c1= $pdo->query($query);

Comment: that's because your query has an error, and $c1 is being set to FALSE, rather than the resource.  Try this: `$c1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` to troubleshoot the error.

Comment: Everything else will work fine only if mysql_query returns a resource. In my other statements it returns a resource but I don't understand why its not doing that in this one.

Comment: @AbsarNaeem - did you follow my suggestion about the die() for troubleshooting? That will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I did but the thing is there is no problem in the query. The problem comes in the while() statement which requires a resource but it gets an object.

Comment: BTW, I'll look into it and try to find a workaround.

Comment: @AbsarNaeem - you're missing the point.  Try the die.  If it returns BOOLEAN, that means the query FAILED.  The query is failing SILENTLY, so adding the die(mysql_error()) will cause it to TELL you why it's failing.  I'm telling you, the query is FAILING.

Comment: It's done. It works great now. All that was needed was to prepare the query. I used the new PDO statement instead of mysql_query.